# Can anyone tell me what bike logo this is? Cant seem to find it

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

Help!!! Please and thank you.!

Answer (score 20):

It's a logo for the [Fit Bike Co](https://fitbikeco.com/)
[image]

With a circle
[image]

[Fit Bike Co logos](https://www.logolynx.com/topic/fit+bike+co)